# Convert an object of class MCHu into a ShapeFile or to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, rgdal, habitat-modeling

I was creating Local Convex Hull Home Ranges in R with the adehabitat package and am unable to figure out how to convert them into Shape files to use in ArcMap.  The methods I've tried seem to require the object to be of class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' or a couple others, but not class 'MCHu'(which is what the Convex Hull Home Ranges are).

How do I convert an 'MCHu' into a 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' or another method to convert 'MCHu' into a shapefile to export into ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [object class definition for "MCHu"](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/adehabitatHR/docs/MCHu). The help indicates "*The class "MCHu" is basically a list of objects of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, with one data frame per animal*". As such, you can just extract a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, for each animal, from the list object.

```
library(adehabitatHR)
data(puechabonsp)

locs <- puechabonsp$relocs
nn <- LoCoH.k(locs[,1], k=12)
class(nn)
plot(nn)

animal1 <- nn[[1]]
class(animal1)
plot(animal1)
```

To write an sp class object to a shapefile you can use the writeOGR function in rgdal.

Alternately, to derive volumes, you could  rasterize the kernel home range estimates using the "MCHu.rast" function.